# What AI predictions can be done using Temperature and Current features of electrical assets?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, ai

I have recently deployed hundreds of IoT based Temperature/Humidity and 3-phase Current sensors on electrical assets/machines(e.g. welding machine, integrated panel etc) in a warehouse and waiting for the data to be collected. The main data collected would be the the machine's temperature and humidity(Celsius) with it's Current (in ampere) and apparent power (kVA). If I were to use these as the features, what analytics can be done or what kind of AI algorithm should I use to show a relation between them for predictive and prescriptive maintenance?